# fastest way to display huge 2D data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, large-data

I have a huge ~9Gb .bin file. 
Reading data with `fread()`, getting 2D array `A` ~ 10^9 points.

Trying to display with `imagesc()` as simple as:

```
    figure(1)
    imagesc(x,y,A)
```

It takes ~ 800 seconds for me and I can't see anything on the figure.
I am sure that I read the file right. Checked with smaller ones.

So I wonder is there a way to display such a huge data with less effort for my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use some kind of downsampling on `A`. To do it right you'd have to apply a low-pass filter followed by decimation, but the low-pass filter may take very long in your case. So, even if it's subject to possible aliasing, you can try to just take a sample out of `n` and plot that:

```
n = 10; %// choose as suits you best
imagesc(x(1:n:end), y(1:n:end), A(1:n:end,1:n:end))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to answer your question without knowing the nature of the data.

Here are some ideas:

- If your data is an image, you should downscale it using on of the known methods, or crop it.
- If you know that your data is smooth, you can sample it without introducing aliasing.
- Show some kind of statistics on your data, instead of showing the data itself.

Comment: It is a scientific calculation so I don't have an information about the smoothness. I guess downsampling will help anyway, thank you